# Phong Reflection Model Parameters

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, algorithms, 3d, optimization

Question: Can anyone refer me the Phong reflection model parameters for a face image taken for web-cam?

Details:

I am doing 3D reconstruction of 2D images using 3D Morphable Model as in this paper [Vetter & Blanz, 2003](http://gravis.cs.unibas.ch/publications/pami03.pdf).

There is a cost function which needs to be optimized using Newton Method. I need to give initialization values for the Newton method.

The below equation is the phong reflection model of an image. The ambient, diffuse and the specualr components are shown.

[image]

[Phong Reflection Model wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model)

Phong Parameters: Ks, Kd, Ka, α, Lm, V

I am estimating the above parameters using Newton method. The image is of human face and the camera is web-cam.

I gave the below values: Ks = Kd = Ka = 0.6
α = 5
Lm = [0 1 1]
V = [0 0 1]

Can anyone comment on the above values and what can be a good initialization values for the parameters??